# UML modelling tool for php

Tags: php, user-interface, uml, draw, modeling

My question is what do you use when you create large scale php applications. I havent found so far a decent UML modelling tools which would have these features:

- nice GUI
- adding attributes and methods by click (no like big edit with raw text and new lines)
- generate php classes
- drag and drop classes

for modelling databases I use MySQL workbench and it is really god for what I need to do.

thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia has [a comparison of UML tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools#Features): look for those that include "PHP" under "Languages generated".

Comment: I tested many of those and none was any good.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: I use phpstorm and it can only create nice uml from code but no modelling, drawing or preparing structure when project does not exists really. So it is not yet a modelling tool but just a visualisation of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could give UML Lab (http://uml-lab.com) a try (Note: I'm biased as I'm working for Yatta Solutions ;) ). The tool supports Java and PHP, and has built-in support for round-trip-engineering. It also brings support for PHP code using a MySQL database.

There are several tutorials available; you could for example start with http://www.uml-lab.com/en/uml-lab/tutorials/modellierung-und-codegenerierung/. The tool is also capable of importing existing PHP source code (reverse engineering).

UML Lab is integrated in Eclipse, so you could for example install the Eclipse PDT to have syntax highlighting and code completion for the generated PHP source files.

It's a commercial tool, but there is a 30 days trial and a free academic edition. If you have any questions don't hesitate asking them in the forum, bug tracker or by mail.

Comment: It look really nice but I must specify variable type which is in php useless. Can I somehow turn it off? Java IDEs are memory hogs all the time but visual side of this app + usage looks good.

Comment: You can add Variables using the Tool Palette on the right hand side of the Class Diagram Editor. This way you can add Properties without having to specify their Type.

Answer (score 0):

[GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com) Matches perfectly your description and you can now customize your own PHP generator following this [tutorial](http://blog.genmymodel.com/build-your-own-php-generator-from-uml-using-acceleo-part-1.html).