# phpstorm, create custom UML diagram

Tags: uml, phpstorm

PhpStorm has a feature to create UML diagrams based on existing classes

But I need to create and save my own diagrams, that will have objects for not existing classes. For example, I need to create a database diagram and a UML diagram for some classes of new feature.

Can I do it via phpstorm?

Answer (score 1):

No, going by the Documentation [Jetbrains Confluence on UML Diagrams in Phpstorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+UML+class+diagrams) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299188/uml-modelling-tool-for-php) phpstorm only allows you to create different UML diagram views of your code base, the only model is your code base itself. Thus you cannot have classes just in a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still of your interest, you can use an extension like [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration) to write your custom UMLs. You can find the documentation [here](http://plantuml.com/)